# Wudhu before sleep do i have to

Tags: halal-haram, wudu

Salaam, if wanting to do wudhu before sleeping does one have to be in purely full clean clothes or is it fine to go sleep in ur sleeping clothes? Also, do i have to do the full wudhu or only the astanja. Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 1):

Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “When you go to bed, do wudu as for prayer.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 247; Muslim 2710).

ref: [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12782/renewing-wudoo-before-going-to-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum. Wuduh before sleeping it is sunnah. If one of muslims skips this a'mal it leads to become ill. Clothes should be clean from najasat, not only for sleeping but every time muslims should wear clean clothes.

Comment: Please provide evidences supporting your claims. How about a person having legal intercourse he/she may also perform wudu'?

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

Following hadith reports that it was sunnah of the Prophet (ﷺ) to perform Wudu before going to bed.

> **Narrated Abu Salama:**
>
> I asked `Aisha "Did the Prophet (ﷺ) use to sleep while he was Junub?"
> She replied, "Yes, but **he used to perform ablution (before going to
> bed)**.
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 286](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:286)

Evidence, that doing Wudu before going to bed is sunnah, is also found in Sahih al-Bukhari 247, Sahih Muslim 307a, Sunan an-Nasa'i 404.

### "does one have to be in purely full clean clothes or is it fine to go sleep in ur sleeping clothes"

Being in a purified state is a condition not only for sleeping. A beleiving man should always be in that state. This is what Allah loves,

> Within it are men who love to purify themselves; and Allah loves those
> who purify themselves.
>
> <sup>[Quran 9:108](https://legacy.quran.com/9/108)</sup>

And orders

> 4.And your clothing purify 5.And uncleanliness avoid
>
> <sup>[Quran 74](https://legacy.quran.com/74)</sup>